# can probability be negative

Tags: probability

I am solving a question that says:

Given that $$P(B)=P(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{2}$$ and $$P(A)=\frac{3}{8}$$
Find

$$P(A\cap {B}^{c})$$

My answer is

$$P(A\cap {B}^{c})=P(A)-P(A\cap B)=(-)\frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: If $P(B)=P(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{2}$ then how can $P(A)=\frac{3}{8}$?

Comment: P(A) cannot be smaller than $P(A\cap B)$ because $A\cap B \subset A$.

Comment: this exact question came in the exam few days ago and I have question paper with me.

Comment: is the teacher wrong

Comment: @asdfgg Where did you get the last equation?

Comment: It came in an exam I had few days ago!

Comment: @asdfgg Do you know the real answer. Was it possibly $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: no, unfortunately I don't have the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the two conditions contradict each other.  The first says that $P(B)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$, and also that whenever $B$ happens $A$ happens, so already we know that $P(A) \ge \frac{1}{2}$.  But the second says that $P(A) \lt \frac{1}{2}$.  The derivation you have carried out is another way to say the same thing (as a proof by contradiction), because negative probability violates Kolmogorov's [first probability axiom](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProbabilityAxioms.html).

On the other hand, [negative "probability" can have meaning](http://cds.cern.ch/record/154856/files/pre-27827.pdf?version=1) if we expand our scope somewhat.

Comment: Should I tell my teacher he is wrong then?

Comment: Good link to Feynman's paper.  I will have fun reading that.  @asdfgg, you can point it out that the question was confusing for the reason that you think it is an impossible scenario, but try to be polite about it and don't say "I think you are wrong."  Word it as "I'm confused about this question for this reason."